# How to delay quit action of quitting app in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I want play some sound just before my app get terminated by user. I can do all the customization that I want if user press quit from app menu, but if user wants quit the app from dock like this:

[image]

I cannot play the sound file, because I have no control on this part, how to delay or control when the real termination should be happen, when the user wants to quit the app from dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`applicationShouldTerminate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428642-applicationshouldterminate) on your `AppDelegate` to tell the system what should happen when a user has requested to terminate the app.

The possible return values are (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/terminatereply):

- `terminateNow`
- `terminateCancel`
- `terminateLater`

Note that when a user choses to quit your app, they are expecting it to quit relatively instantaneously, so you should carefully consider the UX repercussions of delaying a termination like this.

Comment: This way make my timer stop working, the timer is working for showing time and in playing music I am using a timer in this way `RunLoop.current.add(timer1, forMode: .common)` sleep make timer stops.

Comment: You didn't include anything about a `Timer` in your question. I will edit my answer with a different strategy